# Background attachment CSS property won't show over different html elements

Tags: html, css, background, shadow, border-shadow

I am learning the `background-attachment` CSS property, but for some reasons it won't show over textarea's, images, etc.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="scrollbox">
    <ul>
        <li>Ah! Scroll below!</li>
        <li>
            <textarea rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>The end!</li>
        <li>No shadow there.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.scrollbox {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;

    background:
        /* Shadow covers */
        linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,

        /* Shadows */
        radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
        radial-gradient(50% 100%,farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
    background:
        /* Shadow covers */
        linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,

        /* Shadows */
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;

    /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
    background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}
```

Comment: Is you CSS even being included (`html.head.meta` tag) in the page?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, u can use http://jsbin.com/

Comment: ERROR : .scrollbox  Value Error : background farthest-side is not a color value ), radial-gradient(50% 100%,farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%

Comment: @MilchePatern see http://jsbin.com/ilumov/54/edit

Comment: Is this homework ? You can study here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I was right. Your CSS isn't being applied. If you want it to be applied in an online editor, you typically need to omit everything except the contents of the `body` tag. See: http://jsbin.com/ilumov/57/

Comment: @ColeJohnson, your example doesn't solve my problem though. Notice the shadow behind the textarea instead of in front of it

Comment: @MilchePatern , http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ wont help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shadow doesn't appear above anything that is inside the div because it is a background image. It only looks like it is above the text because they are the same colour, if you changed the text colour you would see the text is also above it.

If you visualise div.scrollbox as a literal box and the textarea as a smaller box inside the first. The smaller box would block your view of anything drawn on the base of the larger box.